# Error in logical or in if condition in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, logical-or

i have file category.php which passes `GET['cat']` parameter to process_edit.php

process_edit.php has this code inside..

```
if (!isset($_GET["cat"]) || !isset($_GET["new_field"])) {
    header ("location: category.php"); 
    exit;
    }   
else {      
    if (! ctype_digit($_GET["cat"])) { 
        header("location: category.php");
        exit; 
    }   
}
```

but, when i pass 'cat', it is going in first IF statement rather than going in `ELSE` part.

Can any one suggest what's the error ?

Comment: Is `$_GET['new_field']` set because you have an OR there not an and.

Comment: TO make first if condition fail, you must pass both the variables. otherwise change the condition to `&&`.

Comment: no, `cat` is passing with no error

Comment: i want if any one of them is not set then goto header() and redirect.

Comment: Then it does as you want, if either of those fields are not set, it will enter the first if condition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's break it down :

```
if (!isset($_GET["cat"]) || !isset($_GET["new_field"])) {
```

This means, if cat is not set, OR new_field is not set, then the condition is true.

If you pass cat, but you don't pass new_field, the condition will still be true. If you want it to be false, you need to send BOTH cat AND new_field.

The && requires that all conditions must be true to return true, else it returns false.

The || requires that any of the given conditions must be true to return true, else it returns false.

You can find a complete reference of PHP logical operators here :

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

Comment: but, category.php is passing only `cat` not new_field, new_field is in process_edit.php with form,
so, how can i pass new_field when it's not there.

Comment: You can't, that's why you should use different conditions depending on your page.